# The home page is not the first Google site search result, other pages from the site come first

Tags: homepage, google-site-search

For a few months, when I check my site on Google Search with command `site: example.com` I'm seeing that the main page of the site is below other pages, here is an example:

[image: screen shot of site search results showing home page not first]

I have tried to re-render the main page in GWT on mobile and desktop version, but it didn't help.

I want the main page to be the first hit in Search Results for the command `site: example.com`.

Comment: Why is that a problem?  Users almost never perform site searches, and even if they did, not having the home page first shouldn't cause problems.